# Insert image on current plot without deformation

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, what is the most appropriate way to plot an image with its native aspect ratio, and optionally its native size, inside existing axes at a specific data location?

For instance:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from matplotlib.image import imread
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data

plot([50,60],[1000,2000])
im = imread(get_sample_data("grace_hopper.png", asfileobj=False))
```

Now I want to plot `im` for instance centered at coordinates `(57,1200)` with some scaling or a max height and without deformation.

I imagine that a mix between `matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox` and `matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage` should do the trick, but I'm clearly not familiar with these classes.

Answer (score 2):

As expected, the solution is in the `matplotlib.offsetbox` module:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, gca, show
from matplotlib.image import imread
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

plot([50,60],[1000,2000])
im = imread(get_sample_data("grace_hopper.png", asfileobj=False))    
oi = OffsetImage(im, zoom=0.1)
ab = AnnotationBbox(oi, (57, 1200), xycoords='data', frameon=False)
gca().add_artist(ab)
show()
```

Here is the result:
[image: Well scaled and positioned image inside current plot]

In fact, `AnnotationBbox` does everything needed and alot more with numerous options.